# custom validation checking data into a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, customvalidator

I have this function which lets me put data into my gridview, but I would like to check if the textboxes contain text or either numeric values

```
protected void grdContact_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{            
    DboDocument contact = new DboDocument();

    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
    {
        Label lblNewId_Riga = (Label)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("lblNewId_Riga");
        TextBox txtNewQuantita = (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewQuantita");
        TextBox txtNewUnita_Misura = (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewUnita_Misura");
        TextBox txtNewDescrizione = (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewDescrizione");
        TextBox txtNewPrezzo_Unitario = (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewPrezzo_Unitario");
        TextBox txtNewIva = (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewIva");

        List<DettagliFattura> tmpDettagli = new List<DettagliFattura>();

        if (Session["lst_dettagli"] != null)
        {
            tmpDettagli = (List<DettagliFattura>)Session["lst_dettagli"];
        }

        DettagliFattura Dettaglio = new DettagliFattura();

        Dettaglio.quantita = Convert.ToInt32(txtNewQuantita.Text);
        Dettaglio.unita_misura = txtNewUnita_Misura.Text;
        Dettaglio.descrizione = txtNewDescrizione.Text;
        Dettaglio.valore_unitario = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewPrezzo_Unitario.Text);
        Dettaglio.iva_percento = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNewIva.Text);

        tmpDettagli.Add(Dettaglio);

        Session["lst_dettagli"] = tmpDettagli;


        FillGrid();
        CalcolaTotale();
    }
}
```

Here I want to check if the textboxes are filled with numeric data or text data, but I can't access to those textboxes from my custom validate function

```
protected void ValidatoreTipiDato_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    //if txtNewDescrizione contains numeric data = Args.IsValid = false; etc
}
```

Comment: Why can't you access them from the method?

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: well I was trying to access to the textbox with (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewQuantita"), instead of grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewQuantita")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the `TextBox` using the `args` parameter:

```
protected void ValidatoreTipiDato_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    int x = int.MinValue;
    int.TryParse(args.Value, out x);

    if (x != int.MinValue)
    {
        // It is a number
    }
    else
    {
        // It is not a nuber
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to access the `TextBox` for other reasons you can use the `source` parameter, that in this case it's a `CustomValidator` object, to access its `ControlToValidate` property:

```
protected void ValidatoreTipiDato_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    CustomValidator vc = source as CustomValidator;
    TextBox txt = FindControl(vc.ControlToValidate) as TextBox;

    if (txt != null)
    {
        int x = int.MinValue;
        int.TryParse(txt.Text, out x);

        if (x != int.MinValue)
        {
            // It is a number
        }
        else
        {
            // It is not a nuber
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to access the textbox cause there are many textboxes, and not every textbox has to be numeric. the custom validate function has to control every textbox. I'm going to try to use the code you provided me in the second example

Comment: I combined my code with yours, the following should do the trick:
        
`string quantita = grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewQuantita").ToString();

            if (quantita != null )
            {
                int x = int.MinValue;
                int.TryParse(quantita, out x);

                if (x != int.MinValue)
                   // It is a number
                else
                // It is not a number`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the args parameter to get the textbox value. [Taken from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  protected void ValidatoreTipiDato_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
  {
     try 
     {
        // Test whether the value entered into the text box is even.
        int i = int.Parse(args.Value);
        args.IsValid = ((i%2) == 0);
     }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        args.IsValid = false;
     }
  }
```